# Django Migration errors

Tags: django, django-models

im trying to migrate these models and im getting error.I added the field position,manager which were initially not in my model.made project_name a primary key in Project models:i ran `python manage.py migrate` and i get an error:
Below is the models.

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    position = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    manager= models.CharField(max_length=200,default="x")
    employee_number = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)


class Project(models.Model):
    project_code=models.CharField(max_length=200)   
    employees = models.ManyToManyField(Employee,through="User_Projects")
    project_name= models.TextField(primary_key=True)

class User_Projects(models.Model):
    employee_number = models.ForeignKey(Employee,to_field='employee_number',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project_name = models.ForeignKey(Project,to_field="project_name",on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The error i am getting is below,i need help:

```
InternalError:(1829,"cannot drop column 'id' : needed in a foreign key constraint 'timeapp_user_projects_projects_id_cf8c73ba_fk_timeapp_project_id' of table 'timesheets.timeapp_user_projects'")
```

Comment: just drop the constraint manually and then execute your migration

Answer (score 0):

check your migration file , django might have generated remove field 'id' then created alter command. you can edit the migration file to remove the 'RemoveField' then try migrating. python manage.py migrate